# how to avoid boto3 put_object adds bucket name to path

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Hope someone with deep knowledge of boto3 can help on this, it keeps my team puzzled trying to find out why this is happening.

In one app, we have a S3 client using boto3 that uploads XML files being received from 3rd parties; we have configuration to support S3 endpoint URL, access key, etc. Testing it locally with localstack, everything works flawlessly, but when we put the code in production against our S3 instance, we notice that the bucket name is being added to the key, even though we don't do anything like that in our code.

This is the code we use to get the client (we tested using boto3 resource, too).

```
@cache
def get_client() -> boto3.client:
    if cfg.get_item('s3', 'enable', False):
        params = dict()
        params['aws_access_key_id'] = cfg.get_item('s3', 'access_key_id')
        params['aws_secret_access_key'] = cfg.get_item('s3', 'secret_key')
        params['region_name'] = cfg.get_item('s3', 'region', 'eu-west-1')
        if cfg.get_item('s3', 'token', ''):
            params['aws_session_token'] = cfg.get_item('s3', 'token')
        params['endpoint_url'] = cfg.get_item('s3', 'url')
        return boto3.client('s3', **params)
    raise StorageError('S3 is not enabled, can not get a S3 client ready.')
```

used this way:

```
def put_file(agent: str, operator: str, content: Union[BytesIO, str], path: str) -> bool:
    try:
        bucket = cfg.get_item("s3", "bucket", None)
        # Path will be something like "raw/file_name_1.xml" and bucket like "sw-337381"
        logger.debug(f"Pushing file {path} to S3 bucket {bucket}")
        response = get_client().put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=path, Body=content)

        if 'ResponseMetadata' not in response:
            logger.error(f"Response from S3 for {path} got no metadata, considered to be an error.")
            return False
        logger.debug(f"S3 Response for {path}: {response['ResponseMetadata']}")
        return response['ResponseMetadata'] == 200
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as be:
        logger.exception(be)
        return False
```

However, running this code against S3 does this (cut out the less interesting parts)

```
Changing event name from creating-client-class.iot-data to creating-client-class.iot-data-plane
[...]
Loading JSON file: C:\Users\myuser\Work\myproject\.venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\data\endpoints.json
Loading JSON file: C:\Users\myuser\Work\myproject\.venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\data\sdk-default-configuration.json
Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x0000021E3D93FC10>
Loading JSON file: C:\Users\myuser\Work\myproject\.venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\data\s3\2006-03-01\service-2.json
[...]
Adding expect 100 continue header to request.
[...]
Making request for OperationModel(name=PutObject) with params: {'url_path': '/s3-bucket-337381/raw/myfile_2023041701__operator.1.xml', 'query_string': {}, 'method': 'PUT', 'headers': {'User-Agent': 'Boto3/1.24.43 Python/3.9.13 Windows/10 Botocore/1.27.44', 'Content-MD5': 'cb8Glvk4ymJf27AMUWNn3g==', 'Expect': '100-continue'}, 'body': <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000021E50A3ADB0>, 'url': 'https://s3-bucket-337381.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/s3-bucket-337381/raw/myfile_2023041701__operator.1.xml', 'context': {'client_region': 'eu-west-1', 
'client_config': <botocore.config.Config object at 0x0000021E509334C0>, 'has_streaming_input': True, 'auth_type': None, 'signing': {'bucket': 's3-bucket-337381'}}}
[...]
Using S3 path style addressing.
[...]
CanonicalRequest:
PUT
/s3-bucket-337381/raw/myfile_2023041701__operator.1.xml
[...]
Sending http request: <AWSPreparedRequest stream_output=False, method=PUT, url=https://s3-bucket-337381.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/s3-bucket-337381/raw/myfile_2023041701__operator.1.xml, headers={'User-Agent': b'Boto3/1.24.43 Python/3.9.13 Windows/10 Botocore/1.27.44', 'Content-MD5': b'cb8Glvk4ymJf27AMUWNn3g==', 'Expect': b'100-continue', 'X-Amz-Date': b'20230417T151542Z', 'X-Amz-Content-SHA256': b'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD', 'Authorization': b'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 [...]Certificate path: C:\Users\myuser\Work\myproject\.venv\lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem
Waiting for 100 Continue response.
100 Continue response seen, now sending request body.
```

No idea why this `url_path` or `url` parameters being set to include bucket_name (`'url_path': '/s3-bucket-337381/raw/myfile_2023041701__operator.1.xml'`), while the key never includes it. And this is not happening using localstack, but the surprising thing is that using aws s3api cli it's not happening either.

I've spent several hours debugging and going through boto3 documentation, but I can't find a way to avoid this behavior happening. Anyone with better knowledge of the internals that could give me some light?

Comment: it looks like you're using a _somewhat_ dated version of boto3/botocore, do you see the same problem after updating the packages to newest release?

Comment: also just noticed `Using S3 path style addressing.`... that shouldn't be the default. I think this might be due to explicitly setting `endpoint_url`

Comment: @deric4 that was the exact issue, by setting endpoint_url was forcing addressing style to path, even when we tried using "virtual".

Answer (score 4):

It turned out that, by setting endpoint_url param in the boto3 client to s3, it was setting botocore's Config' addressing_style to "path" mode; which, when the URL points to Amazon-based DNS hosts, adds automatically the bucket as part of the path (since it's the way the path addressing_style works).

By not setting the endpoint_url, it moves into "virtual" addressing-style, and it works flawlessly. Does not matter if you force "virtual" addressing-style, the endpoint_url parameter forces path style to be set.

Something new learnt today!

Comment: nice! glad that worked!